# ListBox seleção

Tags: c#, wpf

Toda vez que movo um item para cima ou para baixo de uma `listBox` ele perde o foco do item.

Não estou conseguindo deixar sempre com foco no item.

Por exemplo: vamos supor que minha lista tenha 200 itens. Então quero mover o item que está na posição 160 para a 159, assim que movida ela perde a seleção (foco) dela, caso queira mover da 159 para a 158 terei que clicar novamente no item e selecionar.

```
public void MoveItem(int direction)
{            
    if (listBox.SelectedItem == null || listBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
        return; 

    int newIndex = listBox.SelectedIndex + direction;

    if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= listBox.Items.Count)
        return; 

    object selected = listBox.SelectedItem;

    listBox.Items.Remove(selected);

    listBox.Items.Insert(newIndex, selected);     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Após mover o item, coloque o mesmo como o selecionado através do seu *index*.

```
listBox.SelectedIndex = newIndex;
```

Caso não tenha acesso ao index desejado, salve o mesmo em uma variável de classe.

Comment: Já tentei essa lógica, mais ele também não funcionou, ele se quer selecionou algum item da ListBox, depurando ele passa o valor certinho..

Comment: Você fez isso dentro do método MoveItem() ou fora? Tente colocar após a execução do método.

Comment: Já tentei fazer dentro e fora.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o `listBox.SetSelected()` para selecionar o item de volta:

```
public void MoveItem(int direction)
{            
    if (listBox.SelectedItem == null || listBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
        return; 

    int newIndex = listBox.SelectedIndex + direction;

    if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= listBox.Items.Count)
        return; 

    object selected = listBox.SelectedItem;

    listBox.Items.Remove(selected);

    listBox.Items.Insert(newIndex, selected);

    listBox.SetSelected(newIndex, true); //Ta aqui o bixo
}
```

Caso tenha duvidas, dê uma olhada na [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: No wpf não tem esse método.

Comment: Tente isso: `listBox.SelectedItem = listBox.Items.GetItemAt(newIndex);`

Comment: Ou isso: `listBox.SelectedItems.Add(listBox.Items.GetItemAt(newIndex));`

Comment: Não , nenhuma das linhas funcionou.

Comment: Estranho. A função `listBox.SelectedItems.Add()` parece a correta para a situação, você só tem que descobrir o que deve passar como parâmetro.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o problema

```
listBox.Focus();
listBox.SelectedIndex = newIndex;
```

inseri no final do código o focus para depois selecionar uma nova index.